# Turn off redirect to canonical domain (or host website on any hostname)

Tags: customization, multisite, redirect

I want to have various development (say `dev.example.com`) and staging environments of a WordPress multisite (`example.com`). For this it would be great if WordPress wouldn't redirect to what it considers the canonical domain name.

I'm running into trouble with this in my `wp-config.php`:

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', gethostname());
```

It redirects to `example.com` or gives me database errors.

This is after `wp search-replace example.com dev.example.com`.

Is it possible to turn off this redirection? If so, how?

Comment: `gethostname())` can't be asked from `wp-config.php`. It's too early. Try `init` or, depends of configuration, something later. Use a plugin, e. g.  `Debug Bar` plus `Debug Bar Action Hooks` to  watch what happens early and what happens later.

Comment: `echo gethostname(); exit();` in `wp-config.php` looks fine to me.
But I'll try `Debug Bar Action Hooks` to see if I can hook around the redirect.

Comment: `exit();` in `wp-config.php` is very bad idea. No WordPress environment in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to modification of `wp-config` you might need to check `.htaccess` too, if there are any pointers to subfolder.

After that, you might need to replace the values in DB tables `wp_site` and `wp_blogs`.

Answer (score 0):

From: [Velvet Blues](http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/turn-off-wordpress-homepage-url-redirection/)

To turn off Canonical URL Redirection, you can add the following code to your theme’s functions.php file.

```
remove_filter('template_redirect','redirect_canonical');
```

or use the plugin: [Disable Canonical Redirects Plugin](http://txfx.net/files/wordpress/disable-canonical-redirects.phps)